# Pre-C++17 replacement for CTAD?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, template-argument-deduction, ctad

#### (Or: "How to store the return value of a template-argument-deduced function where `auto` is not allowed")

I'm working on a generic C++ framework made up of several class templates
that allow to combine specializations of each other.
For external reasons, the language version is restricted to C++14.
Using my framework in non-generic user code ends up in complex template specializations like

```
MyType<foo<bar, baz, quuz<quz>, zip<zap<zoo>>> myObj{
    foo<bar, baz, quuz<quz>, zip<zap<zoo>>{
        bar{},
        baz{},
        quuz<quz>{
            quz{}
        },
        zap<zoo>{
            zoo{}
        }
    }
};
```

Of course, template parameter types do not have to equal the types of ctor arguments,
but in the case of my present code, this happens quite often.
The displayed code is only a caricature of the real code (many more types/templates),
but it should be sufficient to point out my problem
(Please let me know if you need some compilable example code in order to evaluate):

When I cite all the template arguments needed, this causes a lot of noise in the code,
especially for those types that have to be named redundantly.
Type aliases (`using`) do not look like the perfect remedy because the example would need
lots of these, as well.

I inspected the possibilities of [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction), and
I learned that C++14 supports template argument deduction only with function templates
(such as the often-discussed example of `std::make_pair`), but that
[class template argument deduction (CTAD)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction)
will not be available before C++17.

Using function-based template-argument deduction (and "make functions"),
I can "simplify" the object initialization expression on the RHS of the example code above,
which leads to something like

```
MyType<foo<bar, baz, quuz<quz>, zip<zap<zoo>>> myObj = make_obj( 
    make_foo(
        bar{},
        baz{},
        make_quuz(quz{}),
        make_zap(zoo{})
    )
);
```

In contexts where `auto` can be used, I can even reach my goal of brief & expressive code like

```
auto myObj = make_obj(make_foo(bar{}, baz{}, make_quuz(quz{}), make_zap(zoo{})));
```

but this seems to be possible only in certain contexts where, e.g., `myObj` is a local variable.

I would like to realize a framework library that enables users to create their own, non-generic
classes based on my templates, but in a way where they do not have to repeat (and remember) all
the types (= template specializations) used to realize their class implementation, like here:

```
class UserType
{
    public:
        UserType() : m_frameworkImplementation{make_foo(/*...*/)} {}
    private:
        // This is illegal code, of course. Only to show what I'd like to realize...
        auto m_frameworkImplementation;
};
```

Sadly, I'm not able to do anything with `auto` here, and I cannot replace `auto` with `MyType`
if I don't copy all the template arguments to it.

I also made some futile attempts with `decltype`, lambdas and other stuff, but I didn't even gain
a hint on a possible solutions (and it feels to embarrassing to show any of these failed attempts here).
There doesn't seem to be a way to deduce the specialized type of a class template construct, or of
the return value of the deduced specialization of a function template (e.g., "make function"),
at a point where the deduced type is needed to instantiate the type of a member variable.

What did I overlook? Do I have to wait until I can use C++17 or C++20, to achieve the desired result?

Comment: *but this seems to be possible only in certain contexts where, e.g., myObj is a local variable.* You should be able to use it everywhere.  To make it a type just use `decltype(make_obj(make_foo(bar{}, baz{}, make_quuz(quz{}), make_zap(zoo{}))))`

Comment: Here is another way to leverage functions to get types: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72189834/4342498

Comment: CTAD won't help you either. It is also only allowed where `auto` also is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CTAD is not going to help you with this, as the compiler needs to know the type of the members at the line it is parsing the member, unless the class is a template, and `UserType` is not a template.

if the class must not be templated then you can use `decltype` with "in class initialization of members" to create a simpler interface for members as follows.

```
#include <utility>

auto make_foo()
{
    return (int)5;
}

#define DEFINE_MEMBER(var_name, initializer) \
decltype(initializer) var_name = initializer

class UserType
{
    public:
        UserType() {}
    private:
        DEFINE_MEMBER(m_frameworkImplementation, make_foo());
};

int main()
{
    UserType type;
}
```

this [compiles under -std=c++14](https://godbolt.org/z/8ndG5j38T)

you only need to provide a function that returns the "default construtor", you don't need to do it for other constructors.

```
#include <utility>

int make_foo()
{
    return {};
}

#define DEFINE_MEMBER(var_name, initializer) \
decltype(initializer) var_name = initializer

class UserType
{
    public:
        UserType(double val): m_frameworkImplementation{val} {}
    private:
        DEFINE_MEMBER(m_frameworkImplementation, make_foo());
};

int main()
{
    UserType type(1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @AhmedAEK for the hint! `UserType` is not a template intentionally, since the user wants to use a concrete class. Do you see a way to avoid the preprocessor and do something similar with C++14-internal measures, but without copying `initializer`?

Comment: @HelpingHand the type **must** appear on the left of the member variable, so there is no workaround.

Comment: You are right, thanks for pointing this out