Typelist for State Machine
I have two aliases to manage a collection of states for a toy state machine using smart pointers:
using States = std::tuple<std::shared_ptr<State1>, std::shared_ptr<State2>>;
using CurrentState = std::variant<std::shared_ptr<State1>, std::shared_ptr<State2>>;

The example above has two states, but I want, say, 40. Question for my own education: how to use variadic templates (or any other strategy) to avoid repeating the 40-long typelist in both aliases? I'm trying to avoid using an external TMP library.
Possibly related question: I want the object under whose struct these aliases are defined to own the states. Is using smart pointers the way to go here if I'm concerned that every state in my machine is too large to keep all of them in the stack? Hope the question makes sense.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72189606/expanding-a-typelist-into-a-variadic-template/72189834#72189834

Hi Nathan! Thanks for your reply. I did see your post before posting my own question, but I figured that, in my case, I want the Types... in your code to be wrapped by a smart pointer. Furthermore, my question also involves whether to use pointers in the first place. Thanks again!

Whether or not to use pointers is subjective, I can add an answer that wraps in the smart pointer if you really fell you need that.

Do note that in my answer Types... will already be a std::shared_ptr<State1>, std::shared_ptr<State2> since that is the element type of the tuple.

Yes, I did see that, but I wanted to avoid writing down std::shared_ptr 40+ times. Perhaps there's a way to unpack things from some template <typename... Ts> struct States {} where Ts are these 40 states, into a new typelist std::shared_ptr<State1>,...?

So you have a class like template <typename... Ts> struct States {} and you want Ts... to get transformed into the two aliases show in your post?

Exactly, that's what I want.

If you have a class like
template <typename... Ts> struct States {};

and you want to add those aliases to States you can do it like
template <typename... Ts> 
struct States 
{
    using States_t = std::tuple<std::shared_ptr<Ts>...>;
    using CurrentState_t = std::variant<std::shared_ptr<Ts>...>;
};

